# If $A = {6,10,14,\cdots,1002}$ and $B$ is set of divisors of $360$, then what would be the number, and sum of elements in set $A \cap B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, divisor-sum

If $A = {6,10,14,\cdots,1002}$ and $B$ is set of divisors of $360$, then what would be the number, and sum of elements in set $A \cap B$

I have no clue how to do this without actually writing down the entire set of $A$ and $B$ and manually comparing each element. Is there any better way to calculate this?

Comment: You are trying to find all those factors which are divisible by $2$ but not $4$. Any such factor of $360$ is also a factor of $90$ and conversely all factors of $90$ are such factors. Does this help?

Comment: Noting that $$(1 + p + p^2 + \cdots + p^a) = \frac{p^{(a+1)} - 1}{p-1},$$ you have that the sum of the divisors of $$n = p_1^{a_1} \times \cdots \times p_r^{a_r}$$ is $$\prod_{i=1}^r \left[\frac{(p_i)^{(a_i + 1)} - 1}{p_i - 1}\right].$$  The above formula assumes that $p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_r$ are all primes.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani yes, understood!

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that $A$ is double the odd numbers $3,5,7,...501$, so find the divisors of $45$ and double them.

Comment: I now realise that I was a bit careless in my first comment. (Possible that you've realised the error yourself.) In any case, @Arthue has written what I really meant.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani yeah I did understand that. Cause they all have to be even

Answer (score 1):

The comments have already given one way of solving it. Here's a slightly different one.
Note that $360 = 2^{3} \times 3^{2} \times 5^{1}$. Moreover, you're looking for those factors which are divisible by $2$ but not $4$. Thus, any such factor $d$ is precisely of the form $$d = 2 \times 3^{a} \times 5^{b}$$
for $0 \leqslant a \leqslant 2$ and $0 \leqslant b \leqslant 1$.

Can you see that the sum of all such factors is equal to
$$2(1 + 3 + 3^2)(1 + 5)?$$